# how to make checkbox check and uncheck wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have taken checkbox in datagrid

```
<DataTemplate>
  <CheckBox x:Name="chkActive" IsChecked="{Binding Active, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Style="{StaticResource checkboxStyleNormal}" IsEnabled="True"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

and binding the datagrid

```
 datagrid1.ItemSource = dtData.DefaultView;
```

In datatable I am getting Active as `0` and `1`, I want to show my check box checked when `Active = 0`

Grid is binding but I am unable to bind checkbox.

Some one please tell me how to show checkbox check/uncheck based on my condition.

Comment: Have you set the context for your view? Have you implemented the `INotifiyPropertyChanged` interface on your object? Is `Active` a boolean type?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant "_getting Active as zero and one_" so I edited that line too.

Comment: @ChrisF: I am not using INotifiyPropertyChanged interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried by modify my query before binding to the datagrid and added "case" to my query

```
Select ID ,DESC, CASE WHEN [STATUS] = 0 THEN 'True' WHEN [STATUS] = 1 THEN 'False' END AS  [Active], ORDER [Order] from tbldesc
```

its working fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

IsChecked expects a boolean value (true/false) but the table contains a numeric type. You need to add a ValueConverter to the binding statement that will convert the numeric value to a boolean value.

Check [How to bind a boolean to a combobox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335339/how-to-bind-a-boolean-to-combobox-in-wpf) for the inverse case (convert an bool to an int).  In your case, the ValueConverter should be:

```
public class NumToBoolConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((int)value == 1);   
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

This [post](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2009/05/numtoboolconverter-simple.html) has a NumToBoolConverter that also does type and null checking:

```
public class NumToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value!=null && value is int )
        {
            var val = (int)value;
            return (val==0) ? false : true;
        }
        return null;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value!=null && value is bool )
        {
            var val = (bool)value;
            return val ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I am using UserControl for my Design. how can I use windows.resource

Comment: Replace UserControl.Resource for Windows.Resource. Resource is a parameter of its parent object so you need to specify the parent's type, just as you do with DataGrid.XYZ

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps:

- Create a column derived from DataGridBoolColumn
- Override the GetColumnValueAtRow (and SetColumnValueAtRow if you want
  your column to be editable)
- Make these methods call the inherited implementations to work with the
  datasource, but do some pre-/post-processing to convert 0 and 1 to "false"
  and "true" respectively.