# WPF ComboBox initial state from a string property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple combo :

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="testCombo" SelectedValue="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100">
        <ComboBoxItem>OPEN</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>CLOSED</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

That state is just a string property with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.

```
    private string state;

    public string State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("State");
        }
    }
```

What i want to achieve is, when that State string property is initially set to "OPEN", when my window loads, the ComboBox to set it's initial item as "OPEN".

I also tried to attach a converter there:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();

        cbi.Content = value as string;

        return cbi;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as ComboBoxItem).Content;
    }
```

With this, my State string property will be fine populated, but the ComboBox won't get to the desired initial state.

Comment: Where is your code for the State property?

Comment: Open and closed? Converters? is this a bit complex. Can you boil your problem down to: [Bind Combobox to a boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335339/how-to-bind-a-boolean-to-combobox-in-wpf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComboBoxItem` is not compared by content but by reference and the instance you create in converter is not the same instance displayed in `ComboBox` so they will never be equal. What you can do is set `ItemsSource` as list of strings and bind `SelectedItem` directly to string property without any converter

```xml
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="testCombo">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>OPEN</sys:String>
            <sys:String>CLOSED</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

you'll need to add `sys` namespace to your XAML as well

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```